# Swap multiple divs so one class is below all elements with another class with visible animation

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I have multiple divs on a page with different classes named stuff like `position-1`, `position-2`, and `position-3`.

```css
.position-1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.position-2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.position-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.position-4 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="position-1">
  <p>this div has the class position-1.</p>
</div>
<div class="position-3">
  <p>this div has the class position-3.</p>
</div>
<div class="position-2">
  <p>this div has the class position-2.</p>
</div>
<div class="position-4">
  <p>this div has the class position-4.</p>
</div>
<div class="position-2">
  <p>this div has the class position-2.</p>
</div>
<div class="position-3">
  <p>
    this div has the class position-3.</p>
</div>
<div class="position-1">
  <p>
    this div has the class position-1.</p>
</div>
<div class="position-4">
  <p>this div has the class position-4.</p>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmeng/hphdLv4c/).

I want to be able to visually animate the eight divs so that the ones named position-1 are first, then position-2, then position 3, etc when the user presses the button. I don't mind using jquery. I am very new to animations, so I have no idea how to get started.

EDIT: A function would be most useful

Comment: It will be good practice if you add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group it under one parent, sort the array and then animate it using [jquery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function

I also change the `div.position-N` CSS position to absolute

`'top' : i * 30` is 20px height + 10px bottom margin.

```js
var anim = $('.animation > div');

// set default position
$.each(anim, function(i,e) {
    $(this).css('top',i * 30);
});

$('#clickme').click(animateDiv);

function animateDiv() {

    anim.sort(function (a, b) {     
        if (a.className > b.className) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.className < b.className) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    $.each(anim, function(i,e) {
        $(e).animate({
            'top' : i * 30
        },1500); // duration
    });

}
```

```css
.animation {
  position: relative;
}
.animation > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
.animation p {
  margin: 0;
}
.position-1 {
  background-color:red;
  top: 0;
}
.position-2 {
  background-color:lightblue;
}
.position-3 {
  background-color:yellow;
}
.position-4 {
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Click Me" />
<div class="animation">
  <div class="position-4">
    <p>this div has the class position-4.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-3">
    <p>this div has the class position-3.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-3">
    <p>
      this div has the class position-3.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-1">
    <p>
      this div has the class position-1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-4">
    <p>this div has the class position-4.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-1">
    <p>this div has the class position-1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-3">
    <p>this div has the class position-3.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-2">
    <p>this div has the class position-2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-4">
    <p>this div has the class position-4.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-2">
    <p>this div has the class position-2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-3">
    <p>
      this div has the class position-3.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-1">
    <p>
      this div has the class position-1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="position-4">
    <p>this div has the class position-4.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```